# How to fix "Timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool"

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following error seems to show every so often when loading up one of the pages on the site.

"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."

Based on what I found from searching around, it seems that the database connection isn't being closed properly and hence leaking. But I'm not too familiar with ASP.net, so would truly appreciate some guidance.

```
private void DisplayData()
    {
        SqlConnection objCon = new SqlConnection();
        objCon.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        objCon.Open();

        SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand();
        objCmd.Connection = objCon;

        if (Request["Category"] == "some_cat")
        {
            objCmd.CommandText = "Select * From Community Where Category = N'some_cat' Order By Num Desc";
        }
        else if (Request["Category"] == "other_cat")
        {
            objCmd.CommandText = "Select * From Community Where Category = N'other_cat' Order By Num Desc";
        }
        else if (Request["Category"] == "Blog")
        {
            objCmd.CommandText = "Select * From Community Where Category = N'Blog' Order By Num Desc";
        }
        else if (Request["Category"] == "All")
        {
            objCmd.CommandText = "Select * From Community Where Category != N'Blog' Order By Num Desc";
        }


        objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter objDa = new SqlDataAdapter();
        objDa.SelectCommand = objCmd;

        DataSet objDs = new DataSet();

        objDa.Fill(objDs, "Community");

        this.ctlList.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
        this.ctlList.DataBind();

    objCon.Close();

    }
```

Comment: A connection object is a disposable object. Failing to dispose it could lead to this error. Learn how to use the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) (On all your SqlConnection instances)

Comment: Side note: you could write a parameterized query to avoid all that if logic.

Comment: @Steve Would you be able to provide me an example using the code I posted?

Comment: it simply _using(SqlConnection objCon = new SqlConnection()) { .... all the current code less the objCon.Close().....}_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is possibly originated by the missing dispose of the connection object. A disposable object should be *disposed* (IE calling its Dispose method) to release all the unmanaged resources contained in the object. The *using statement* will make this easy because, even in case of exceptions, it calls the Dispose method for the object enclsed in its starting block.

A using statement is a simple way to write a try/finally block

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
try
{

}
finally
{
    con.Dispose(); // And this will also close the connection
}
```

So your code could be changed to:

```
private void DisplayData()
{
    using(SqlConnection objCon = new SqlConnection())
    using(SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
         objCon.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        objCon.Open();

        objCmd.Connection = objCon;
        objCmd.CommandText = "Select * From Community Where Category = @cat Order By Num Desc";
        objCmd.Parameters.Add("@cat", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Request["Category"].ToString();

        if (Request["Category"] == "All")
        {
           objCmd.CommandText = "Select * From Community Where Category != @cat Order By Num";
           objCmd.Parameters[0].Value = "Blog"    
        }
        SqlDataAdapter objDa = new SqlDataAdapter();
        objDa.SelectCommand = objCmd;
        DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
        objDa.Fill(objDs, "Community");
        this.ctlList.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
        this.ctlList.DataBind();
}
```

Of course, to remove the connection pool problem you should check all your code where you create an SqlConnection and implement the using block.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation and code.